# Rails HTML5 offline database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

Are there any examples, gems, or plugins that would provide a good starting point for a Rails app that utilizes an offline database? Bonus points if it deals with syncing the offline database to an online database.

Or, is it preferred use straight JavaScript for this?

Comment: Ruby, when used in a server-side context, cannot access client-side DBs without 'straight Javascript' or a similar client-side framework.

Comment: Is there something along the lines of RJS that wraps HTML 5 offline database functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at [Rack::Offline](https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline)

It handles creating the manifest and has other nifty features as well. But, all told, you will need to get into the nitty-gritty with 'straight-javascript'.

Comment: If I had the rep, I'd +1 this answer. It makes sense that there isn't a plugin since offline access never hits the framework. I am now thinking of building some rake tasks that would do some scaffolding of the HTML pages and JavaScript. Maybe it could dynamically generate cache manifests based on the content needed by a given page. Anyway, thanks for the link.

Comment: Now I am working on one project where I am using backbonejs, persistencejs, rack-offline for creating offline version of my website. For backbonejs you can write your own sync module based on navigator.onLine variable.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen it by now, but check out [Railscast episode 247](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1)s 247 and 248.  In 248 he mentions that a plugin does not currently exist so you have to code it in Javascript for now.